# How can I compute the average eigenvalue of a parametrised matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a family of $n\times n$ parameterised Hermitian matrices, the simplest of which is of the form:

$$
\mathrm{M}(t) = f(t)\mathrm{I} + \mathrm{Q}
$$
where $f(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$, $\mathrm{I}$ is the usual $n\times n$ identity matrix and $\mathrm{Q}$ is a known $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix. I need to compute the (arithmetic) mean of each of the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_\alpha(t)\}$ of $\mathrm{M}(t)$ over an interval $a \leq t \le b$. What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: the more general case is 
$$
\mathrm{M}_{nm}(t) = f(t,n)\delta_{nm} + \mathrm{Q}_{nm}
$$
where $f(t,n)$ is a polynomial in $t$ and $n$.

What I have done so far is to write the mean of the $\alpha$'th eigenvalue $\lambda$ as

$$
\bar{\lambda}_\alpha = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \lambda_\alpha(t)dt 
$$
then approximate the integral as a discrete sum over regularly sampled values of $t$. This works relatively well as far as accuracy is concerned, but requires a matrix diagonalisation for each sampled value of $t$ which is time-consuming and not always practical.

Is there a way to compute the mean value directly (e.g. with a single matrix diagonalisation)? I could easily integrate $\mathrm{M}(t)$ over this interval to get the arithmetic matrix mean, but it is not clear to me whether I could obtain the mean eigenvalue from this.

(Note that the trace is not sufficient, I need the mean of each individual eigenvalue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Qx_i=\lambda_i x_i$ then $M(t)x_i=(f(t)+\lambda_i)x_i$. So,
$$\bar{\lambda}_i(M)=\lambda_i+\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(\tau)d\tau$$

Comment: I've edited the question to add a more general case that I also need to solve, where the parameterisation is not a scaled identity but a more general diagonal matrix. Can the above approach be extended to handle that case?

Comment: In this case you can only find some bounds. The idea is similar as above but you get inequality instead of equality, using Weyl's inequality or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues of matrix $M$ are the roots of $\det(M-\lambda I)=0$. Or in your case:
$$
\det(Q+f(t)I-\lambda I)=\det(Q-(\lambda-f(t)I).
$$

Thus, if $\lambda(0)$ is an eigenvalue at $t=0$, then $\lambda(\tau)=\lambda(0)+f(\tau)-f(0)$ is an eigenvalue at $t=\tau$.

Comment: Excellent! There's a more general form, where the parameterisation is not just a scaled identity but a diagonal matrix. Is there anything straightforward there? I've edited the question to add this in.